# After $K$ balls are drawn, what is the probability that next ball drawn is green.

Tags: probability

An urn contains $m$ green and $n$ red balls. $K (< m, n)$ balls are drawn and laid aside, their colour being ignored.
Then one more ball is drawn. Then the probability that it is green.

What I don't understand is that how do we write favorable cases when one more ball is drawn as color of $K$  balls was ignored in first draw.

Answer given is $\frac{m}{m+n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A green ball is equally likely to appear anywhere in the sequence.  Since $m$ of the $m + n$ balls are green, the $(k + 1)$st ball selected has probability 
$$\frac{m}{m + n}$$
of being green.  To see this, imagine lining up the $m + n$ balls in some order in the dark, then reaching for the ball in the $(k + 1)$st position.

Comment: But on $(k+1)$th draw, urn has only $m+n-k$ balls?

Comment: That is irrelevant.  Imagine any permutation of the balls in a row.  Think of a selection as being in the order the balls appear in that permutation.  What is the probability that the ball in the $(k + 1)$st position is green?

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear.